# Undefined rate from "SAR-USD". magento 2

Tags: magento2

I changed the default currency in my store to be SAR, but I got this error on checkout page:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Undefined rate from "SAR-USD". magento 2
```

Any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In admin, you have  **`another currency USD.`**

And  **SAR  to USD** conversion rate does not set at `admin>Store>Currency Rate`. You Should currency rate manually .

Or you use Magento default currency rate provide WebserviceX to set Currency rate by CronJoB[image]

There are some useful blog:

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-currency-magento-2.html
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-configure-currency/

### Or, you can resolve this issue by remove USD from currency list

So,

**Go to Stores >> Configuration >> Currency Setup (under General tab).**

**Most Important note that: Please Flush magento cache from Command Prompt after changes**